# parted with "free" option, results in invalid token in some cases

Tags: parted

when parted with "free" option is run when there is unallocated space at end of the disk (not consumed by partition), I get this error..

```
[root@sprintlab423vm4 ~]# parted /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:03:00.0-scsi-0:0:1:0 unit MB print free
Error: The backup GPT table is not at the end of the disk, as it should be.  This might mean that another operating system believes the disk is smaller.  Fix, by
moving the backup to the end (and removing the old backup)?
parted: invalid token: free
Fix/Ignore/Cancel? Ignore
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sdb appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 20971520 blocks) or continue with the
current setting?
Fix/Ignore? Ignore
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 783832MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End       Size      File system  Name     Flags
 1      1.05MB  773093MB  773092MB               primary


[root@sprintlab423vm4 ~]# rpm -qa | grep parted
parted-2.1-25.el6.x86_64
```

Same command works in other cases where I suspect the disk is completely allocated via partitions..(dont see the warning)

```
[root@blrvse12vm04 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)

[root@blrvse12vm04 ~]# parted /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:03:00.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 unit MB print free
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 102005MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start    End       Size     Type     File system  Flags
        0.03MB   1.05MB    1.02MB            Free Space
 1      1.05MB   158MB     157MB    primary  ext4         boot
 2      158MB    91268MB   91110MB  primary               lvm
        91268MB  102005MB  10737MB           Free Space

[root@blrvse12vm04 ~]# rpm -qa | grep parted
parted-2.1-29.el6.x86_64
```

Why would it not recognise "free" when it spews out the warning for the unallocated space?